# How should I access a JMX MBeanServer running in the same VM?

Tags: java, web-applications, jmx, mbeans

For a simple Java library which performs operations in constant intervals I have implemented JMX management using MXBeans and it works as expected, I can query the status and set parameters, supend / resume the operations etc in JConsole.

Now I would like to create a web application - to display and control the library operation.

I don't know wether it is a good idea to use the samy JMX API also in the web application, so I need a way to access the MXBeans which are registered in the same VM using the platform MBean Server:

MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

I noticed that the MBeanServer has a queryMBeans method. Should I use this method to access the registered JMX API MXBeans? There is a different path, using JMXConnectorFactory, which requires protocol, host, and port information so that the client can access a remote JMX server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you only want to access the MBeanServer in the same JVM, then `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();` is the way to do it.

`JMXConnectorFactory` is for accessing remote MBeanServers (i.e. in a different JVM, and/or on a different host).